# Crystal Report Is Not showing while it is installed already latest version (VS2012 AND VS 2019)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have already installed version 13.0.33.4333 but it's not showing reporting option in VS 2019 while if I open VS2012 and click on reporting it just opening two file for create

1. rdlc file
2. another but crystal report is not showing

I installed many versions of crystal report but it is not giving option of reporting when i click on add new item in VS2019

while in VS2012 it is giving option of reporting but just 2 report

1. rdlc
2. another but crystal report is not showing[this is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQb8z.png)